# Iterating Stores over a set of Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Morning All,

I  am looking for an efficient way of solving the following issue:
(Please note that I have simplified and changed the actual problem; however that should not reflect on the result that I am looking for)

Basically, If I want to identify the number of transactions for each `Store` owned by a particular company, grouped by Date, I have to run the following query:

```
Select 
date_of_transaction 
,store
,COUNT(*)
from transactions t1
group by date_of_transaction,store
order by date_of_transaction
```

However, this query is not sufficient since it does not return the `stores` and `dates` where the number of transactions is equal to '0'

For instance, if there are not any transactions commited by `store A` on `1/Oct/2012`, the ROW will be missing from my resultset.

Thats why, I want to force in all 365 days for the past year and then display each `Store` for every single `Date`.
In other words,if the company owns 3 stores, I need 3 records for each day of the year, even if the number of transactions is '0':

```
Date        Store      Number
1/1/2012    A          1
1/1/2012    B          0
1/1/2012    C          3
2/1/2012    A          1
2/1/2012    B          2
2/1/2012    C          0
3/1/2012    A          1
3/1/2012    B          0
3/1/2012    C          0
```

I have a Calendar table, which I have used to 'UNION' the stores and force them in, however it has to be a better way of doing it.

Regards
Kiril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, should do what you want (you need to base your query off of your calendar and store tables, to get all dates and all stores in the output, and then LEFT JOIN the transactions table):

```
SELECT Calendar.Date, Stores.Store, COUNT(T1.transaction_id) AS Number
FROM Calendar, Stores
LEFT JOIN Transactions T1 ON T1.date_of_transaction = Calendar.date 
    AND T1.store = Stores.store
GROUP BY Calendar.Date, Stores.Store
```

Comment: I am not able to identify any relations between the calendar and Stores table.

Comment: So what? The query above does not rely on a relation between those two. It does a cartesian join (so that you get every record in the Stores table for every record in the Calendar table). It only relies on a relation between the Transactions table and the Stores table, and between the Transactions table and the Calendar table.

Comment: Nevermind, I have joined them `on cal_daydate between isnull(vw.Store_Start_Date, '19000101') and ISNULL(vw.Store_End_Date, GETDATE())`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Common Table Expression for calculating distinct stores and dates.

Below is a test table with data from above.

```
--
-- My database
--

-- Play in temp
use tempdb;
go

-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE my_transactions
(
  my_id INT identity(1, 1) primary key,
  my_date DATETIME,
  my_store CHAR(1),
  my_sale MONEY
);

-- Insert some data
INSERT INTO my_transactions (my_date, my_store, my_sale) 
VALUES
('1/1/2012', 'A', 100),
('1/1/2012', 'C', 100),
('1/1/2012', 'C', 100),
('1/1/2012', 'C', 100),
('2/1/2012', 'A', 200),
('2/1/2012', 'B', 200),
('2/1/2012', 'B', 200),
('3/1/2012', 'A', 300);

-- Show the data
SELECT * FROM my_transactions;
```

[image]

I will use a tally table concept to create the month begin dates, stores, and create the report.

```
--
-- My report query
--
;
WITH cteMonths (my_number, my_date) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number,
        DATEADD(M, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) - 1, '2012-01-01') as my_date
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
),
cteStores (my_store) as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT my_store FROM my_transactions
)
SELECT 
    MS.my_date,
    MS.my_store,
    COUNT(T.my_id) as my_total
FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM cteMonths CROSS JOIN cteStores WHERE my_number < 4 ) MS
LEFT JOIN
    my_transactions AS T ON MS.my_date = T.my_date and MS.my_store = T.my_store
GROUP BY
    MS.my_date,
    MS.my_store
ORDER BY
    MS.my_date,
    MS.my_store
GO
```

[image]